# Crear Visor de imagen con transición de la miniatura a completa en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Tengo una galería de imágenes usando un `ViewPage`, me gustaría implementar un visor de imagen a pantalla completa, es decir que cuando se haga click sobre la imagen se abriera un visor de imágenes, el visor común de muchas apps, como por ejemplo la de WhatsApp, en detalles de perfil de un contacto al pulsar sobre la imagen.

Con algunas de las siguientes características:

- De la miniatura hacia el visor de la imágen, se realice con efecto de
  transición de zoom
- Fondo negro y Imagen proporcionada centrada verticalmente.
- `Toggle Click` sobre la imágen para hacer aparecer o ocultar la `ActionBar` con efecto fadeOut y fadeIn
- si se rota el dispositivo se expande la imágen.

Comment: Busca en github, https://github.com/yanzhenjie/Album, nadie te podrá ayudar a realizar lo que pides a medida, pero puedes partir de algo hecho como esta por ejemplo, si te vale como respuesta avisa please!

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo abrirlo via Intent

```
            String realPath = FileServices.getPath(getContext(), Uri.parse(_DESCRIPTION.getLocalURI()));
            File tempFile = new File(realPath);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(tempFile), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```